# Цвет Radio button в Яндекс браузере

Tags: css, radio-input, яндекс-браузер

[image: обработка цвета]

Столкнулся с тем, что Яндекс.Браузер не реагирует на изменения цвета радио-кнопки.

Вот сайт с примером:
https://usefulangle.com/post/389/css-radio-button-color

Браузеры Firefox, Chrome меняют цвет, а Яндекс.Браузер использует свой чёрный цвет.

Может кто-то сталкивался с этим уже и знает решение?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/checks-radios/#radios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, Яндекс.Браузер на текущий момент (до версии 22.9.5.710) не поддерживает css-свойство [accent-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color).

Можно написать им в саппорт и подождать, пока поддержку добавят в новых версиях.

Или можно игнорировать браузерные стили с помощью свойства [appearance](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/appearance) и задать свои стили инпутов с помощью свойств background и border, как это сделано, например, в [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/checks-radios/#radios), ссылку давали в комментарии к вопросу

Comment: да, благодарю за подсказку. На самом сайте (но, не в примерах) getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/checks-radios/#radios
реализован способ, где кнопка прячется, а вместо неё используется рисунок (векторная графика).
В поддержку яндекс браузера написал, кто знает, может позже введут поддержку свойство цвет акцента.